# how to run a When a resource event occurs based on file name?

Tags: azure, conditional-statements, azure-logic-apps

i have a workflow in logic app that i'd like to run based on file name. it works fine without the condition, but more than i want. so  used this condition to restrict the runs of the Workflow

```
@or(contains(triggerBody()?['Name'],'example.csv'),contains(triggerBody()?['Name'],'Hello.csv'))
```

Body of the Firstelement:

```
   {
  "topic": "/subscriptions/5665-56-56-56-56/resourceGroups/nameResources/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/name",
  "subject": "/blobServices/default/containers/output/blobs/hello.csv",
  "eventType": "Microsoft.Storage.BlobCreated",
  "id": "45-45-45-45-456",
  "data": {
    "api": "PutBlob",
    "clientRequestId": "45-45-4fd8-45-45",
    "requestId": "45-45-0028-5346-45",
    "eTag": "45",
    "contentType": "text/csv",
    "contentLength": 5432,
    "blobType": "BlockBlob",
    "blobUrl": "https://name.blob.core.windows.net/output/hello.csv",
    "url": "https://name.blob.core.windows.net/output/hello.csv",
    "sequencer": "66666",
    "identity": "$superuser",
    "storageDiagnostics": {
      "batchId": "66-66-66-66-66"
    }
  },
  "dataVersion": "",
  "metadataVersion": "1",
  "eventTime": "time"
}
```

The Workflow:

[image]

is this condition based on the filename correct?

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. My question to you is, does it work? I assume it doesn’t because you’re here on SO asking the question and one can only assume you’ve tested it. If not, show us the trigger body JSON and maybe we can help.

Comment: @Skin when there's no trigger (when workflow won't run) how i'm supposed to provide JSON & triggerbody

Comment: @MostafaBouzari Can you add where you are facing the issue or maybe the flow of your logic app helps us troubleshoot whether the ask works or not

Comment: @MostafaBouzari so what’s your trigger? You said it runs fine if you don’t have the condition. Therefore, provide the trigger body in your question. You should provide as much information as possible.

Comment: basically i want to trigger based on the file's name

Comment: You’ve said, “body of the first element”, does that mean your trigger body contains an array? If so, it might have been better to include the entire trigger body text, not just the first element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest trying something like this ...

```
@or(contains(string(triggerBody()),'example.csv'),contains(string(triggerBody()),'Hello.csv'))
```

Simplifies having to traverse the JSON structure.

I tested that concept and it worked for me.

Comment: tnx it works, but why we need to convert to string?

Comment: Because otherwise you have to be specific about what to select from within the JSON structure.  The chances of `hello.csv` being in the payload and **NOT** being what you want is that rare it's not funny so just easier to search for it within the string representation of the payload.  In order to do that, you need to convert it to a string first.  Make sense?